# Show that $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$.

Tags: general-topology

Show that  $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$.

I have tested this exercise using case disjunction, one of the implications was very cumbersome nonetheless. I would like to know a more sophisticated point test for this exercise.

Definition: $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if $x$ is in the closure of $A \setminus \{x \}$.

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a topological space and $ A $ be a subset of $X$. The derivative of $A$ is the set of all $A$ limit points and is denoted by $A'$.
That is, the derivative of a set is the set of all accumulations points of this set.

Comment: Please define $A'$ more properly.

Comment: You almost certainly mean the complement if you're referring to topology.

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the entire set and $B$ is the empty set.

Comment: The derivative of a set is the set of all accumulations points of this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $A \subseteq (A \cup B)$ so $A' \subseteq (A \cup B)'$ and in the same way, $B' \subseteq (A \cup B)'$, and combining these we get

$$A' \cup B' \subseteq (A \cup B)'$$

Now, if we had some $x \in (A \cup B)'$ and $x \notin A'$ and $x \notin B'$ (so the if the reverse inclusion would *not* hold) then $x \notin A'$ means we have an open neighbourhood (or ball around $x$, in a metric space) $U_x$ of $x$ such that $A \cap U_x \subseteq \{x\}$ (the intersection could be empty, or it could be $\{x\}$, I don't care) and similarly we have an open neighbourhood (or ball) $V_x$ such that $V_x \cap B \subseteq \{x\}$. Then take $O_x= U_x \cap V_x$ (or the ball with the smallest radius of the two, in a metric space, same idea) and note that

$$O_x \cap (A \cup B) = (O_x \cap A) \cup (O_x \cap B) \subseteq (U_x \cap A) \cup  (V_x \cap B) \subseteq \{x\}$$

and this contradicts $x \in (A \cup B)'$. So the reverse inclusion *does* hold

and $$(A \cup B)' \subseteq A' \cup B'$$

as required. No case distinctions required, but one inclusion goes via the contrapositive.